# How to handle race condition in stock reading and updating in mysql laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, race-condition

I am working on a software where multiple sale orders comes through excel files. My problem is that multiple csv files of sale orders are uploaded to my system. System parses these files in jobs. If all files have the order of same product i.e PRODUCTA, all orders read the remaining stock at the same time. It is, let say 20.  3 orders come, first one needs 8 quantity 2nd one needs 5 quantity and 3rd one needs 15 quantity. now what happens is very interested. All three reads remaining stock at the same time and it is 20. all three requests can see the stock is 20 and each request take its stock and update the remaining stock according to its figures. For example first one update the reamaining stock as 12 2nd one do 15 and 3rd one do 5. In actual, it should be -8. i have handled if stock is not available but ignore that part for now and focus on the problem i am facing right now. Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is a mutex. A mutex will allow you to lock all relevant parts of the application until you are done processing, then release those parts.

Here is some more information on mutex setups:

https://wpdesk.net/blog/mutexes-deadlocks-and-other-developer-nightmares/

... and here is a popular PHP implementation:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html

EDIT: Depending on how simple your system is, a mutex may also be overkill, with database transactions sufficing to make things atomic enough for your needs.